# Python - Searching String In Text File

Tags: python

im new into python and i wanna do some searching string in txt file.
I've been doing crawling some tweet using TwitterSearch API Twitter and then export it into txt files.
In my txt files, it has some sentences like :

```
1|@tephen_ian|@mypreviana ya yg tabrakan maut itu lo... Antara KA 225 sama 220 thn 1987 itu... Yg bintaro 2 itu td pagi|None
2|@adibnurazis|Warga Jakarta korban tabrakan Bintaro ditanggung Pemprov DKI http://t.co/joKjmTKc0S http://t.co/8ebRc8AjzK|None
3|@randhika1991|Turut brduka cita utk Tabrakan KRL vs Truk LPG di Bintaro. Smg Amal Ibadah Korban yg mninggal ditrima oleh Tuhan YME, Aamiin... :( @KAI121|None
4|@ErhamORI|#Bagas Korban KRL vs Truk BBM: Tewas 5 Orang, Luka Berat 9, Luka Ringan 82: Kecelakaan tabrakan KRL dengan tru... http://t.co/a0lmnWQ0TQ|None
5|@appsari|@rararararatri iya. Ada tabrakan KRL jurusan serpong-tanah abang, nabrak truk solar, trs kebakar. Bnyk korban jiwanya..|None
```

And from that txt files, i wanna search some sentences that contains a few words / query like 'tabrakan', 'di', 'antara', 'tewas', 'luka', 'selamat' and then print sentences which contains that words.

So far, ive doing this :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

data = open("dataset.txt", "r")
for line in data:
        line_split = line.rstrip("\n").split("|")
        if line_split[2] == 'tabrakan' 'di' 'antara' 'tewas' 'luka' 'selamat':
                print(line_split[0])
```

and didnt have any result.

Am i doing wrong?
Hope anyone could help, cause im done trying using whoosh or any text classifiers :(
I'm sorry if im using Indonesian in my crawl dataset.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search for string in txt file Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/search-for-string-in-txt-file-python)

Comment: Try to print `'tabrakan' 'di' 'antara' 'tewas' 'luka' 'selamat'`, and see what it is actually equal to.

Comment: @guisantogui: What has that got to do with the actual problem at hand here?

Comment: @guisantogui: the other question doesn't teach anything about finding *multiple* possible matches.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary where and how im supposed to print? sorry if a dumb question, i just get lost

Comment: @user3084137 Try it in the shell. `print 'tabrakan' 'di' 'antara' 'tewas' 'luka' 'selamat'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Search a list of strings for any sub-string from another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749342/search-a-list-of-strings-for-any-sub-string-from-another-list)

```
keywords = ['tabrakan', 'di' ,'antara', 'tewas', 'luka', 'selamat']
for line in data:
    if any(k in line for k in keywords):
        print line
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, finally I came up with my solution :).